# Override existing HTML Element attribute and property with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was wondering if its possible to override existing HTML Element attribute and property accessors (getters and setters) with Javascript so that when html is rendered by browser all the assignments to certain attributes in the html code are preprocessed with custom functionality.

Here is an example :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

// JS code would go here which would override default behavior 
// for example if I wanted to reformat id="name"  so its actually
// registered as id="pre_name" once browser renders the html  


</script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- here we are assigning the 'name' to id , but behind the scene we really want it to be 'pre_name' -->
<div id="name"></div>

<script>
    // when we try to access the id it would actually match the overwritten one 
    console.log(document.body.children[0].id)  // would output pre_name
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is something like that possible and how?
I know that I can traverse the dom after it's rendered and change all of the ids, but I am wondering if its possible to intercept the assignment of properties and attributes and do it at that level before browser even renders the html.

Example I presented is just made up one to present the problem and make is simple to understand.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's possible (which it isn't, you can't add properties to objects that doesn't exist yet), it makes no sense to do this.

Comment: Is this for the sake of stylesheet or script versions? If so, why not just use the same ID for the different CSS or scripts, and dynamically load the desired one? Or are you just generally curious? I'd wonder what the usage would be, but I doubt that the browser is going to invoke property accessors when creating the DOM.

Comment: I was trying to solve another issue of a much bigger project that I got curious about this idea, I think if it was possible there would be some good use for it when it comes building javascript frameworks and libraries.. etc

Comment: Well, it was an interesting thought anyway. There certainly could be some clever uses for it, but I'm almost glad it's not allowed. :-)

Comment: There is not much thats not allowed when it comes to javascript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, you can only modify the `name` element after it is loaded.
So it would be something like this:

```
<body>

<!-- here we are assigning the 'name' to id , but behind the scene we really want it to be 'pre_name' -->
<div id="name"></div>
<script>
    // right after
    document.getElementById('name').id = 'pre_name';
</script>

<script>
    // when we try to access the id it would actually match the overwritten one
    console.log(document.body.children[0].id)  // would output pre_name
</script>

</body>
```

or even

```
<body>

<!-- here we are assigning the 'name' to id , but behind the scene we really want it to be 'pre_name' -->
<div id="name"></div>

<script>
    // or here
    document.getElementById('name').id = 'pre_name';
    // when we try to access the id it would actually match the overwritten one
    console.log(document.body.children[0].id)  // would output pre_name
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html [data-*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attributes for second value like;

```
<div id="name" data-second="pre_name"></div>
```

And then you can use,

```
var div = document.getElementById('name');
div.getAttribute("data-second");
```

Comment: I don't think this really has anything to do with what is being asked.

Comment: Overriding is not possible, I have suggested alternative way

Comment: It's a good solution if he wants to associate data with elements. But I think what he's after is a way to invoke code upon the creation of certain properties. Property accessors can do this (maybe) after the DOM is loaded, but I doubt they'll fire while the DOM is being creation

Comment: Cookie monster is correct, I am trying to intercept the assignment of attributes in html so that I can manipulate values or maybe store them somewhere for later use. Yes I know I can do all this by traversing the dom but I was looking for a possibly different solution.

I tried using Object.defineProperty() and __definegetter__ & __definesetter__ but that didn't work